# Does a Flask Request Run to Completion before another Request Starts?

Tags: python, flask

I ask because I'm wondering if I can get away with using a text file as a data store for a simple app. If each handler runs to completion, then it seems like I should be able to modify the text file during that request without worrying about conflicts, assuming I close the file at the end of each request.

Is this feasible? Is there anything special I need to do in order to use a text file as a data store in a Flask app?

Comment: Use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) if you want a single file database; you also can use a [cache](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/caching/). Do not re-create a db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end, a Flask application is a [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) application, which means that it is simply a Python function that looks like this...

```
def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    # environ is a dict, start_response is a callable.
    # This function should call start_response, then return an iterable of strings
    # that make up the body of the response.
```

Flask implements this function in a way that it calls a bunch of other functions in the flask package, which eventually hands off control to you. By then, the data structures have changed, but the entire process is just a way to easily write code that implements this one function correctly.

This function is called by a web server (sometimes using some module, such as the [modwsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) module for Apache). Of course, this one grand function must be loaded into some instance of Python in order to be called.

Say your web server has a wsgi module. When the web server starts, the module will create a single Python process that has up to four threads. When a new request comes in, it grabs one of the unused threads, and calls the above function on it. Then, all of the rest of Flask and your application's code is called, still within that thread. Another request, however, calls the same function, but now in another thread. The reason this works is because Flask has explicitly made it possible to be run in such a multi-threaded mode, but Flask does not actually control whether it's run in multiple threads. Of course, one process and four threads is completely arbitrary: your server could very well using multiple processes and a dozen threads each. Or one process and one thread.

So, the true answer has nothing to do with Flask, because Flask is just an app written using the WSGI protocol. The [WSGI protocol decision on Multi-Threading](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#thread-support) states...

> Thread support, or lack thereof, is also server-dependent. Servers
>   that can run multiple requests in parallel, should also provide the
>   option of running an application in a single-threaded fashion, so that
>   applications or frameworks that are not thread-safe may still be used
>   with that server.

So, if you truly wish to run your Flask application in single-threading mode, you need to look at your specific server and/or module as to how the WSGI application is run. The server/module will probably have a way to configure your application to run in a single thread.

Regarding whether forcing a single-threaded system and storing items in a text file is a good idea, that's pretty subjective.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that there is no guarantee of that. However, it depends on how you're running the application. If you're using Heroku+gunicorn for example, all files on Heroku that are changed during a request are not kept, i.e., the files are ephemeral. So if you were to change the text file, the changes would not persist through to the next request. Another provider, PythonAnywhere, is not so strict about their filesystem, but again, the requests would have no guarantee of one finishing before the next could start. Moreover, for a modern web server, that would be a useless application (or more accurately server).

Also if you want a small database, just use sqlite. As long as it is installed on the system, python comes with a library for interacting with it (if I remember correctly).